# Eqv Capacitance of a Spherical Shell half filled with a Dielectric Medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Given below is the diagram of a Spherical Shell filled with a Dielectric Medium in right half of the Shell.

[image]

> Find the Equivalent Capacitance of the given Shell.

**Attempt:**

We know that the Equivalent Capacitance of a regular Spherical shell is given by

$C{_e}{_q} = \frac{4\pi\epsilon_o}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}}$

For the half part of it, the above expression becomes half ([@]don't know if that's correct)

And for the other half

$C = \frac{2k\pi\epsilon_o}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}}$

Now, since these two halves have the same Potential Difference, they can be considered in **Parallel**.

Therefore, the Equivalent Capacitance of the given shell becomes

$C=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_o}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}} + \frac{2k\pi\epsilon_o}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{2(k+1)\pi\epsilon_o}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}}$

Now I don't know if this [@] part is correct or not. Plus I am not sure about the right answer .

I would be really grateful if you correct me in this one.

Comment: Your attempt seems correct, if I am not mistaken. Also, I think this video explains something similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClpNNNDAEGI